# The system cannot find the txt file specified in java

Tags: java

I'm making a program that opens and reads png and txt files. This is my code:

```
public static void init() {
        //...
        //compiler are finding a path for png files...
        menu = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/menu.png");
        options = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/options.png");
        level = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/levelmenu.png");
        levelOptions = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/leveloptions.png");

        //..., but no for txt
        map[0] = new LoadMap("/textures/lvl1.txt");
        map[1] = new LoadMap("/textures/lvl2.txt");
        map[2] = new LoadMap("/textures/lvl3.txt");
        map[3] = new LoadMap("/textures/lvl4.txt");
        map[4] = new LoadMap("/textures/lvl5.txt");
        //...
}
```

but when I run it, I get this error:

```
 \textures\lvl1.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 \textures\lvl2.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 \textures\lvl3.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 \textures\lvl4.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
 \textures\lvl5.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

my files lvl1...5.txt and menu...levelOptions.png were in the same directory

LoadMap constructor:

```js
public LoadMap(String path) {
  try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

    String s = " ";
    s = reader.readLine();
    String[] wordsXY = s.split(" ");
    x = wordsXY[0];
    iX = Integer.parseInt(x);
    y = wordsXY[1];
    iY = Integer.parseInt(y);

    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      String[] words = s.split(" ");
      for (int i = 0; i < iY; i++) {
        arrayList.add(Integer.parseInt(words[i]));
      }
    }
    reader.close();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

ImageLoader class:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
        try {
            return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

SOLUTION:

The problem was in loadMap class.

Instead:

```js
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
```

should be:

```js
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you share the code of `LoadMap`?

Comment: Well it sounds like it can't find those files - do you *actually* have a `textures` directory in your root directory? That sounds unlikely. Note how `loadImage` uses `Class.getResource`, which is very different from creating a `FileReader`.

Comment: You're right. My texture folder directory is: myproject/res/textures/png&txt files.
Method loadImage skips res folder. Now, when: map[0..5] = new LoadMap("res/textures/lvl1.txt") it's fine

Answer (score 1):

`ImageLoader` loads resources from classpath, whereas `LoadMap` loads them from your file system, hence the difference results.

More specifically, this returns an `InputStream` correspoding to a file with path `path` from classpath of `ImageLoader` class:

```
ImageLoader.class.getResource(path)
```

And the following creates a `Reader` that reads from a file from the *file system*:

```
new FileReader(path)
```

You should use the same mechanism for both cases to get the same results.